# How do I put these conditions on an equation using GEKKO?

Tags: python, gekko

I have 3 conditions for an equation in a system that is being solved:

1. If `P > S` and `H < S`, then `y = -k(S-H)`
2. If `P < S` and `H < S`, then `y = -k(P-H)`
3. If `H > S`, then `y = 0`

How would I add these conditions to an equation?

I tried using `if3(condition,x1,x2)` with an "and" statement in the condition i.e. `if3(P>S and H>S, -k(S-H),-k(P-H))`

It did not work. I got this error:

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py:25, in GK_Operators.__len__(self)
 24 def __len__(self):
---> 25     return len(self.value)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py:144, in GK_Value.__len__(self)
143 def __len__(self):
--> 144     return len(self.value)

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Gekko if3 function acts as a conditional against 0, where the x1 parameter is chosen if the provided conditional is below 0, and the x2 parameter is chosen if the provided conditional is above 0. I don't believe logical expressions like "<" or "and" will work with the Gekko syntax. You can accomplish an "and" with a nested if3 statement, like so:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

P = m.Param(5)
S = m.Param(5)
H = m.Param(5)
k = m.Param(5)

cond1 = P - S
cond2 = H - S

#x1 is cond<0
y = m.if3(cond2,m.if3(cond1,-k*(P-H),-k*(S-H)),0)

m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value[0])
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.